# How can I find the number of users who visited a certain page type x amount of times in a month?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

In Google Analytics, I need to find the number of unique visitors who generated page views on a certain type of page. I want to know how many unique visitors visited 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5+ articles in a month - similar to the basic report "visitors frequency recency", but for page views on articles instead of sessions. I can filter the page type "articles" via the URL, every article has an "id-" in the URL. I don't care whether the users visited other types of pages like my index page or not. It would be awesome if you had an idea on how to tackle this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is here, you could go Behaviour > Site content > All pages, then filter for the article part in your URL using the search function.

Comment: Unless you want 1 article total viewed: 20 unique users, 2 article total viewed: 15 unique users?

Comment: In that case, you could create custom dimensions (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en); each user's article visit would add to his/her hit counter. Not sure how the set-up would look exactly, though.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is creating a new segment, setting its conditions to Unique Page View = x AND Page = /article/, but I'm not sure if that'll do the trick.